# After Table Joining, need specific row value based on another Row with same ID

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables as follows:

Table 1:

```
ID  FName
1   Basics
2   Machine1
3   master
4   Machine2
15  Machine3
16  Machine16
```

Table 2:

```
ParentID    Name            InitialValue
1       Active          1
2       MachineName     Entrylevel
2       Active          1
3       Active          1
4       MachineName     Midlevellevel
4       Active          1
15      MachineName     Endlevel
15      Active          1
16      MachineName     Miscellenious
16      Active          0
```

Here, ID of Table 1 is referred as Parent ID at Table 2. I want "Initial Value" of Table 2 for MachineName Rows (of Table 2) provided "InitialValue" of Table 2 for Active Rows (of Table 2) are 1

Result should be like

```
ID  InitialValue
2   Entrylevel
4   Midlevellevel
15  Endlevel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the second table twice, once for MachineName, and once for Active:

```
SELECT     t.ID, machine.InitialValue
FROM       table1 t 
INNER JOIN table2 machine 
        ON t.ID = machine.ParentId
       AND machine.Name = 'MachineName'
INNER JOIN table2 active 
        ON t.ID = active.ParentId
       AND active.Name = 'Active'
       AND active.InitialValue = 1;
```

### About Joins

The `JOIN` syntax allows you to link records to the previous table in your `FROM` list, most of the time via a relationship of foreign key - primary key. In a distant past, we used to do that with a `WHERE` condition, but that really is outdated syntax.

In the above query, that relationship of primary key - foreign key is expressed with `t.ID = machine.ParentId` in the first case. Note the alias that was defined for table2, so we can refer to it with `machine`.

Some extra condition(s) are added to the join condition, such as `machine.Name = 'MachineName'`. Those could just as well have been placed in a `WHERE` clause, but I like it this way.

Then the same table is joined again, this time with another alias. This time it filters the "Active" 1 records. Note that if the *ID* in table1 does not have a matching record with those conditions, that parent record will be excluded from the results.

So now we have the table1 records with a matching "MachineName" record and are sure there is an "Active" 1 record for it as well. This is what needs to be output.

Comment: works like a charm....I am still trying to understand the 2 joins you used....Thanks a ton...if you can briefly explain...I am not much familiar with Joins

Comment: Hey trincot: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I really started understanding the whole logic now...thanks a ton...You saved a lot of my time and I learned new thing as well....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.InitialValue
FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ParentID
WHERE t2.name LIKE 'MachineName'AND t1.ID= ANY(SELECT t22.ParentID
                                                  FROM table2 t22
                                                  WHERE t22.InitialValue=1)
```

I think this should work

//slightly changed the condition in WHERE clausule (t2.parentID changed to t1.ID)

Comment: this works but also gets me the machine which are inactive (Initial Value =0 ..i.e. ID16)....so looks like close but not the one I need....also trying other friend's help...

Comment: Changed it a little bit. Please, Try now.

Comment: Hel Hector-Thanks for trying. it still did not worked. I think, you missed the "ACTIVE" machine status from Name column to compare- Below one worked for me (slightly modified your query at the end)..
SELECT t1.ID, t2.InitialValue
FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ParentID
WHERE t2.name LIKE 'MachineName'AND t1.ID= ANY(SELECT t22.ParentID
                                                  FROM table2 t22
                                                  WHERE t22.InitialValue=1 AND t22.name=Active)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is standard SQL but it should work using MySQL.

```
select T1.ID, T2.InitialValue
from Table1 T1 inner join Table2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ParentId
where
T2.Name <> 'Active'
and exists (
  select * from Table2 T3 where T3.ParentId = T1.ID and T3.Name = 'Active' and T3.InitialValue = 1
)
```